# Why i can't use String variable in "RequestBody.create(mediaType, String)"?

Tags: java, rest, okhttp

I have:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "12345");
```

...and it's work fine.

But it doesn't work if i use:

```
String str = "12345";
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, str);
```

or

```
String str = new String ("12345");
```

Why?....

[About this method](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/RequestBody.html)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Try this `RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, str.toString());`

Comment: It's request from Postman.
Example:
`RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "[ {\r\n  \"id\" : \"089\",\r\n  \"additional-params\" : [\r\n  \t\r\n    {\r\} ]");`

Comment: i haven't error, but it doesn't work, because post request is wrong (

Comment: How is it wrong then?

Comment: The problem is that you open 2 brackets and 2 curly brackets but only close one of each.